# triple integral: order of integration

Tags: calculus

I am trying to evaluate the volume of the solid below the plane $z = 1+y$, bounded by the coordinate planes and the vertical plane $2x + y = 2$.
$$V=\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{2-2x}\int_{z=0}^{1+y}\,\mathrm dz\mathrm dy\mathrm dx$$ which gives $5/3$. the problem arises when I tried to evaluate the volume by changing the order of integration as follows:
$$V=\int_{z=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{z-1}\int_{x=0}^{1-\frac{y}{2}}\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dydz$$
which gives $-7/12$.

Comment: I haven't looked at the whole expression yet but did you know that $z$ runs from $0$ to $3$?

Comment: Next, $y>z-1$ but also $y>0$

Comment: no it's not, but I tried it and the result wasn't 5/3 as it should be

Comment: At first sight I think there are more small errors here, so that is why you don't get $5/3$ immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[z<1+y\right]\left[2x+y<2\right]dxdydz=\int_{0}^{3}\int_{\max\left(0,z-1\right)}^{2}\int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{2}y}dxdydz=$$$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{2}y}dxdydz+\int_{1}^{3}\int_{z-1}^{2}\int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{2}y}dxdydz=1+\frac{2}{3}$$

Here e.g. $[z<1+y]$ denotes the function that takes value $1$ for $(z,y)$ that satisfy condition $z<1+y$ and takes value $0$ otherwise.